# Selecting that particular div class name among but not other divs which have other classes as well available using beautifulsoup or selenium

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

this is a tricky problem from my side where I was stuck into the webscraping part and was not able to proceed further.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4tN2.png

**I need only grid-cell answers in a loop**

I tried using

`grid_cell=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#tags-browser > div:nth-child(2) > div.mt-auto.grid.jc-space-between.fs-caption.fc-black-300 > div:nth-child(1)')`

Now displaying the text of the tag will show 2061748 questions

`grid_cell.text`

but this is only for one element.

What if I wanted to have it in a loop where I need all the count for all the tags available in that page?

In this case, as per image, I iterated a for loop over '''javascript''' and '''java'''
but
get_element_using_css_selector would give a a specific count for either java or javascript but not for both.

And also if I choose

`tag_counts = body.find_all('div', class_='grid_cell')`

then I would get other classes also that are below grid-cell in the picture attached which are to be excluded.

Please suggest some solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: post the website url and what you want to extract

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways of achieving this:

**First option:**
Remove the tags you don't want to scrape and then scrape the tags that you do want. For example:

```
tags = body.find_all('div', class_='grid_cell s-anchor') # TODO: add full class name (to remove this tag) 
for tag in tags:
    tag.extract() # Remove tag from body

tags = body.find_all('div', class_='grid_cell') # This will contain all the tags you want.
```

**Second option:**
Loop through parent html tag and get the first tag using find(). For exmaple:

```
containers = body.find_all('div', class_='mt-auto grid') # Find parent tag 
for container in containers:
    tag = container.find('div', class_='grid_cell') # Get first tag in the container div
    print(tag.text.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, Looks good. I shall try it and let you know

Comment: I tried using this: 

`#now get the count of all the questions in each tag

containers = body.find_all('div', class_='s-card js-tag-cell grid fd-column') # Find parent tag 

for container in containers:
    tag= container.find('div', class_='grid jc-space-between ai-center mb12')
    tag_count = container.find('div', class_='mt-auto grid jc-space-between fs-caption fc-black-300') # Get first tag in the container div
    print(tag.text.strip())
    print(tag_count.text.strip())`

Comment: But it gave me wrong data: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eq2jg-a34cEpwTNvf915C_OYLB-MkI8o/view?usp=sharing